# Counting pairs of array elements where one is a multiple of the other

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Count all pairs (i,j) in an array where arr[i]%arr[j]==0 or arr[j]%arr[i]==0.

Of course, the obvious O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution is to traverse the array twice; but can anyone suggest a more efficient way?

Comment: Are the array elements bounded?

Comment: Any efficient solution if suppose they were?

Comment: Then you can do something that looks like a prime number sieve.